# Ошибка DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist с кастомным профилем

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Проблема такова: при инициализации вебдрайвера с кастомным профилем, сразу после открытия браузера следует его краш со следующим логом

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome
\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that C
hrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b
90),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

Часть кода, отвечающая за инициализацию браузера:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=C:\\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\\Selenium\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 1):

я взял ваш код и он заработал без аргумента: `options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");`

вероятно отключая все расширения при запуске, вы тем самым отключаете возможность ChromeDriver управлять браузером